# Why principal publishing messages to the SNS encrypted topic needs kms:GenerateDataKey and kms:Decrypt?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, amazon-kms

Currently I am reading this document - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/encrypting-messages-published-to-amazon-sns-with-aws-kms/

And I found: "*First, the principal publishing messages to the Amazon SNS encrypted topic must have access permission to execute the AWS KMS operations **GenerateDataKey and Decrypt**....*".

Why the **principal** needs to have these two operations `kms:GenerateDataKey` and `kms:Decrypt` if SNS is SSE enabled?
Is these being used by message encryption in transit? But the SNS API already had all messages in transit with Transport Layer Security (TLS) certificates issued by ATS.

I tried to create a Lambda function to trigger a SNS topic with SSE enabled, and this document is correct that a Lambda needs to have these two operations (actions) or it will fail when trying to create subscription.

PS. I know what the meaning of `kms:GenerateDataKey` and `kms:Decrypt`. But my question is "**why principal (caller) needs to have these two operations if SNS is encrypted**"?

Answer (score 1):

I also kind of stumbled upon this topic and found your question quite interesting. I did some research and tried to understand what happens when using different kind of resources with encryption at rest based on KMS in AWS.
So this is my take on it, if it is wrong, I'm very happy to be corrected.

If you publish to a SNS topic with encryption enabled, you *implicity* request to

1. generate a data key using the configured KMS key for the topic
2. verify the integrity of the newly generated data key by decrypting it again.

These actions are triggered and executed by SNS on behalf of the principal calling *publish* , who must therefore have the appropriate permissions.
This is explained in the [SQS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-key-management.html#sqs-what-permissions-for-sse) but should apply in the same way for SNS Topics.

One can also compare it to S3 encryption, which allows to explicitly set the SSE for an object by using the x-amz-server-side-encryption header.
When a bucket has a default encryption enabled, it will
apply it if no such (vaild) header is sent, in which case the caller also needs to have the permissions for the configured default KMS key,
like in the case of an SNS Topic.